# Open a worksheet sheet in a different workbook by clicking on a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is there an Excel feature to open a worksheet in a different workbook? For example, say I have a workbook called invoice.xlsx and another workbook called service.xlsx. In the invoice workbook, there's a worksheet called inv111 that is associated with worksheet srv222 in the service workbook.

If I'm working in inv111, when I click on the cell where srv222 is mentioned, I want the service workbook to open with the service worksheet srv222 active/displayed.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer addresses the original wording of the question, which asked how to refer to a worksheet in another workbook.  It doesn't answer the question as currently worded.  However, the OP may need this as additional information for his application, and someone marked it as useful, so I will leave it in place with that caveat.*

To refer to a cell on another worksheet, the syntax would be:

`[service.xlsx]srv222!$A$1`

That is, filename in brackets then sheetname followed by exclamation point followed by cell reference.  If it is on another worksheet in the same workbook, you can leave off the filename.

Incidentally, that is one of the kinds of metadata you can get from the CELL function, using the "filename" parameter.  See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-7be7fcb3-fa19-407c-b78f-e096e2345a5e) for more information on the CELL function and [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/214084/EN-US) for more information on how to use it for this purpose..  That allows a cell to "self-identify" its location, which can then be used in a formula.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what I want is, when I click on one of the "A" worksheet, it will open up worksheet "B" (diff workbook), no particular cell (the whole sheet).

Comment: @Chris: that's very different from the description in the question.  Let's see if we can clarify the question to get you a better answer.  So are you looking for something where you, say, click on a link in the invoice worksheet and it opens a worksheet in the service workbook?  Or, the two workbooks open together, with the service workbook opening to a specific worksheet?  Or the two workbooks open together, and clicking on a link in invoice changes the active worksheet in Service to a specific one?  Describe the exact action you're looking for.

Comment: 2 workbooks, i.e invoice & service. In invoice workbook, let's say there's one worksheet called inv111 with attached service sheet srv222. When I click on inv111 (the cell where srv222 is mentioned), the service workbook should open with the service worksheet srv222.